# How can I access viewbag in a class library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class-library, viewbag

I have a solution that have a class library and a mvc project.

I need to have a method in the class library that change viewbag. But i cant access to viewbag from class library project.

What should I do ?

Comment: Trying to use the viewbag within a class library is a bad design. The viewbag is meant to pass information between controller and view

Comment: Actually i want to use viewbag to make an alert class. The method in alert class will fill a viewbag and in my layout if there is the specific viewbag then it writes in the HTML. Do u know any better way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  ViewBags don't extend anything that can be passed as a parameter.  I'm referring specifically to the viewbag itself, not the variable properties.  You can pass those, as objects.  You have other options though.  You could replace the ViewBag with a session variable.  Session variables can be directly accessed inside models by referencing them like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["error"] = "error!";
```

and of course you can easily reference this in an index page or controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the Viewbag into the Method?

Where are you using the class library in your MVC project?

Update: You are calling the class library from the controller

Here is an example if your viewbag is for ice cream and your class library calculates price.

1. In controller and viewbag is set to chocolate.
2. Call class library and pass Viewbag.Icecream.ToString()
3. Return from class libray "$1.50"
4. Pass the returned data to the view

Comment: I cant pass viewbag to method. Because it doesnt have setter. I cant undrestand the second question!

Comment: From what method in your mvc project are you calling the class library project.  From the controller? from a view? from some other class?